# Generation of plot legend names in GNU Octave

Tags: octave

I would like to generate the legends of a plot in GNU Octave, based on how many lines I plot, how do I do this?
The names of each legend should be the same except a number in the name.

Here is what i do now:

```
W = 3
data = zeros(W, 1000);
% Calculate data...
plot(data.');
legend("w1", "w2", "w3");
```

The problem arises when I change `W` to some other value, then i have to manually update the legend call with more or less strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i=1:W
  leg(i,:)=strjoin({"W",int2str(i)},"");
endfor
legend(leg)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer.
Though, it leaves to another question.
When i set `W` to a value of or bigger, i get the error `nonconformant arguments (op1 is 1x2, op2 is 1x3)`.
Can this be avoided with this solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the name of the line in the `plot` command, through the `DisplayName` line property. `legend` will use these names:

```
clf; hold on
plot(data(1,:), 'DisplayName','w1');
plot(data(2,:), 'DisplayName','w2');
legend;
```